# how to automatic add word in values after insert table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have this table:

```
create table a(
id_a number(5) not null, 
name varchar2(15) not null, 
address varchar2(30), 
phone varchar2(12), 
constraint pk_a primary key (id_a)
);
```

after i insert into table,
i want to add the word automatic behind the values in field "name".

1, Grace, Aussie, 0111111

then, i want to after insert this. the value Grace automatic add S, Comp behind the word.

1, Grace S.Comp, Aussie, 0111111

thanks

Comment: Huh? What do you mean?  Where does "S. Comp" come from?  Please be specific.

Comment: why do you want to modify names? what if you later need the original name?

Comment: i want add keyword S.Comp automatic in field name after i insert into table a.

Comment: you'll be wanting to lookup BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER in the manual

Comment: if it is a static keyword that you'll be adding to all your names, you could use a view, or add a virtual field to append that suffix. If it is a title that may change between rows you could add a column to store it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger (before insert - for each row):

```
create trigger your_trigger_name before insert on a for each row
  when (new.name is not null)
begin
  :new.name := :new.name || ' S.Comp';
end;
```

This trigger will change "name" column automatically (only when "name" is not null).

Comment: can i insert that without trigger? but with procedure or function.

Comment: Yes you can, but then you cannot use direct insertions, then you must always call the procedure to insert in the table.